# How to find linear function if two points are given?

Tags: calculus, functions

[image: Example]

Determine the parameterization of $x_1 (t)$ of curve $C_1$ with $t∈ [0,1]$

From the picture I see two points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ (red dot). I calculated that function is $y=2t$ but solution is $y=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{2}t$.

Can my solution also be correct or only the the solution from book?

P.S. $C_1$ is this linear function on the picture, there is also $C_2$ which curve is from $\frac{\Pi}{4}$ to $\Pi $ but $C_2$ is not important for my question!

Comment: but the point $(1,1)$ does not fulfill the equation $$y=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{2}x$$

Comment: Can you just use the point-slope formula from Algebra II for this?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Sorry. I edited my question. What about now?

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic One of the easiest ways to parameterize a function $f(x)$ is to set $x(t) = t$ and then set $y(t) = f(x(t))$. While it's not necessarily the best way, it's not incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I assume from your picture that you have a circle of radius $3$ and an angle of $\pi / 4$. With some trigonometry, you can deduce that the point at the end of $C_1$ is $(3\sqrt{2}/2, 3\sqrt{2}/2)$. You want $t = 0$ to correspond to $(0,0)$ and $t = 1$ to correspond to $(3\sqrt{2}/2, 3\sqrt{2}/2)$, so 
$$
\mathbf{r}(t) = \left\langle \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2} t, \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2} t \right\rangle
$$
will do the trick. (I used $\mathbf{r}(t)$ rather than $x_1(t)$ to emphasize that my function is describing both $x$ and $y$ positions simultaneously.) If you prefer a system of parametric functions rather than this vector function, then it could be written
$$
x(t) = \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2} t
$$
$$
y(t) = \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2} t
$$